# Organize files attached to a node into folders

Tags: 7, files

We need to organize files attached to a page into folders (with Drupal 7). They don't necessarily have to be physical folders, virtual folders are fine.

Do you know a module like this, or do we have to implement it our own?

Update:
To be more specific: we need the ability to display attached files on the page organized into folders, the underlying filesystem structure is indifferent.

Comment: I see someone has -1'd the question. Could you also please add a comment why is it wrong and how I could improve it?

Comment: Did you look at the [Filedepot](http://drupal.org/project/filedepot) module ?

Comment: We ? is it a joint account :P

Comment: @kantu: Me, Myself and I :) (actually a few of us are trying to get this done here)

Comment: May be a hierarchical taxonomy list with Views ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make a taxonomy vocabulary to simulate the folder structure. Install [File Entity](http://drupal.org/project/file_entity) module. It makes fieldable files, so you can attach taxonomy for the file own - with the module [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) you can do that during editing the node.

To display files grouped by folders, you can make a view to do that, and use [EVA](http://drupal.org/project/eva) to embed it into the node. In the view you have to make a 'File' based view, just add a relationship to the node, and add a Content Id contextual filter, which use that relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Filefield](http://drupal.org/project/filefield) module.

> Configurable upload paths allow you to save files into per-field or
>   per-user directories. FileField does not need a Drupal 7 version
>   because it has been moved to Drupal Core! To upgrade FileField to
>   Drupal 7, install the Drupal 7 CCK Package and use the Content Migrate
>   to upgrade FileField to Drupal 7.